# fetchall function of zend adapter class not working

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, mysql-error-1242

Am getting the following error.

Exception information:

Message: SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row

Why does fetchall giving problems for querying multiple rows???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible cause is that the subquery follows '=', '>', ... in an expression and returns more that one row.

Or can you post the SQL statement for further discussion?

Comment: Thanks, that was the answer. But anyways i found the solution before your reply :)